# What is gained by transforming a convolution to an addition with the cepstrum?

Tags: fourier-transform, speech-recognition, cepstral-analysis

In automatic speech recognition the spectrum $f$ is interpreted as the convolution of elicitation $e$ and impulse response $h$.
By applying the cepstrum $cep(f) = FT^{-1}(log(FT(f)))$ this convolution is turned into an addition:
\begin{align}
               f   &=                e   &*                h\\
            FT(f)  &=             FT(e)  &\cdot         FT(h)\\
        log FT(f)  &=         log FT(e)  &+         log FT(h)\\
FT^{-1}(log FT(f)) &= FT^{-1}(log FT(e)) &+ FT^{-1}(log FT(h))
\end{align}

This is apparently 'neat' and helps to separate the two. But I don't understand how that is. The goal as I understand it is to filter for relevant features. Addition is certainly an easier operation than convolution but we still only have the resulting spectrum (or cepstrum of) $f$. Before, we don't know the value of the two quantities convoluted, after, we don't know the values of the two quantities added.